# Why is my constructor not instantiating the variable?

Tags: java

Why is the value of `clowns` equal to `0` for the below?

If I print `numOfDecks`, it prints out `3`, as expected.

```
public class CardSet {

private static int numOfDecks;
char suits [] = {'a','s','h','c'};
char ranks [] = {'A','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','T','J','Q','K'};

public CardSet(int number){

    if (number > 0) {
        this.numOfDecks = number;

    }
    else this.numOfDecks = 3;
}

public static int getNumOfDecks(){
    return numOfDecks;
}

static int clowns = numOfDecks;

public static void main (String [] args){
    CardSet cards = new CardSet(3);
    System.out.println(clowns); //prints out 0
    System.out.println(numOfDecks); // prints out 3
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This sets the *parameter* variable's value:

```
else numberOfDecks = 3;
```

Which is **not** what you really want to do. Instead it should be:

```
else this.numberOfDecks = 3;
```

Which sets the field's value. Or more succinctly you could do:

```
public CardSet(int numberOfDecks){
    this.numberOfDecks = (numberOfDecks > 0) ? numberOfDecks : 3;
}
```

As a side note, consider using enums for your suits and ranks, since this is one of the [classic examples given for their use](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/enums.html).

Comment: I have changed the code a little bit based on your suggestions, however its still not working for me.

Comment: @summerNight: please don't go shifting requirements on us as that makes it very difficult to answer questions. But the **new** question is answered by checking when you set clowns's value: It's done at variable declaration time which is **before** the constructor has been called. So it is no surprise that it uses the initial value of numberOfDecks.

Comment: And static, static, static.

Answer (score 1):

I think, at first, numOfDecks = 0, clowns is set to the same value as numOfDecks. When you create the constructor, the numberOfDecks is set to new value as your condition inside the constructor. But the clowns is not set again. So, I think you should write a method getClowns() instead of calling the properties clowns as your current code.

```
public class CardSet {

    private int numOfDecks;
    char suits [] = {'a','s','h','c'};
    char ranks [] = {'A','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','T','J','Q','K'};
    private int clowns;

    public CardSet(int numberOfDecks){

        if (numberOfDecks > 0) {
            this.numOfDecks = numberOfDecks;
        }
        else numOfDecks = 3;
    }

    public int getNumOfDecks(){
        return numOfDecks;
    }

    /**
     * set the clowns from NumOfDecks and return it
     * @return int value
     * */
    public int getClowns() {
        clowns = getNumOfDecks();
        return clowns;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CardSet cardSet = new CardSet(2);
        System.out.println(cardSet.getNumOfDecks());
        System.out.println(cardSet.getClowns());

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I get it :) Pretty much all global vars are defined before the constructor of the class is called right?